# Fedora grub builds menu including non-existent entries from LinuxMint

Tags: grub

Here's the boot menu:
[image]

The system was originally a Windows system where I later created a new partition (on a different drive) and installed LinuxMint 21.2.  Subsequently, I've installed Fedora 39 to a new partition on that same drive where LinuxMint is installed so the Fedora partition is now where the initial boot occurs. (NOTE: I've renamed `30_os-prober` to `05_os-prober` so Windows is found earlier and gets put at the top.  I'm in the process of moving off Windows and still want to keep the LinuxMint install around for some other testing.)

Fedora, in configuring its grub entries, added a list of entries for LinuxMint which aren't valid -- all of them except the 5.15.0-91-generic entries aren't actually there and weren't there before I even installed Fedora.

How do I convince Fedora to get rid of all the invalid entries?  I'm not sure why it put them there since they -- well, they aren't valid; it isn't possible to boot into them.  At one point, prior to installing Fedora, I had tried different kernels on LinuxMint but those were all removed and I'd settled on the original 5.15.0.  Those were all removed before I even installed Fedora. And prior to installing Fedora -- when initial boot was to LinuxMint -- it showed just the two entries for LinuxMint on the 5.15.0 kernel.

Ideally, it should just list:

- Windows Boot Manager...
- LinuxMint 21.2 Cinnamon...
- Fedora Linux... 39 (Cinnamon) --
  for booting into Fedora

Answer (score 0):

I found that rebuilding the grub menu worked to remove all the additional entries:
`sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /etc/grub2.cfg`

Still not sure why it added all the others in the first place.